# Opencv fails to save video when cropped using numpy slicing

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm using OpenCV (3.4.6) to capture video from a Raspberry Pi HQ camera, attached to a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian 10. Bounding boxes suggested by an object detection algorithm are then drawn onto the captured frames, and the output saved to a video file.

Everything works great, except when I try to crop the video to my region of interest.

Using the following line successfully crops the image (as confirmed by `cv2.imshow`):

```
frame = frame[0:720, 280:1000]
```

But, it also stops the output being saved by `out.write` - I just get an empty file, and being new to both Python and OpenCV, I'm struggling to work out why.

I've trimmed down the code to the relevant part below (apologies - it's still a bit long - I'm not entirely sure what might be important):

```
# begin video capture
    try:
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(int(video_path), cv2.CAP_V4L2)
        
    except:
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    out = None
    
    # set capture resolution     
    inputcodec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G') # forces MJPG codec
    vid.set(6, inputcodec) # sets inputcodec for video capture
    vid.set(3, 1280) # sets video capture width
    vid.set(4, 720) # sets video capture height
    
    if FLAGS.output:
        # by default VideoCapture returns float instead of int
        width = int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        height = int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        fps = int(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*FLAGS.output_format)
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(FLAGS.output, codec, fps, (width, height))

    while True:
        return_value, frame = vid.read()
        frame = frame[0:720, 280:1000] # crop video to square region of interest
        if return_value:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image = Image.fromarray(frame)
        else:
            print('Video has ended or failed, try a different video format!')
            break
    
        frame_size = frame.shape[:2]
        image_data = cv2.resize(frame, (input_size, input_size))
        image_data = image_data / 255.
        image_data = image_data[np.newaxis, ...].astype(np.float32)
        start_time = time.time()

        if FLAGS.framework == 'tflite':
            interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], image_data)
            interpreter.invoke()
            pred = [interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[i]['index']) for i in range(len(output_details))]
            if FLAGS.model == 'yolov3' and FLAGS.tiny == True:
                boxes, pred_conf = filter_boxes(pred[1], pred[0], score_threshold=0.25,
                                                input_shape=tf.constant([input_size, input_size]))
            else:
                boxes, pred_conf = filter_boxes(pred[0], pred[1], score_threshold=0.25,
                                                input_shape=tf.constant([input_size, input_size]))
        else:
            batch_data = tf.constant(image_data)
            pred_bbox = infer(batch_data)
            for key, value in pred_bbox.items():
                boxes = value[:, :, 0:4]
                pred_conf = value[:, :, 4:]

        boxes, scores, classes, valid_detections = tf.image.combined_non_max_suppression(
            boxes=tf.reshape(boxes, (tf.shape(boxes)[0], -1, 1, 4)),
            scores=tf.reshape(
                pred_conf, (tf.shape(pred_conf)[0], -1, tf.shape(pred_conf)[-1])),
            max_output_size_per_class=50,
            max_total_size=50,
            iou_threshold=FLAGS.iou,
            score_threshold=FLAGS.score
        )
        pred_bbox = [boxes.numpy(), scores.numpy(), classes.numpy(), valid_detections.numpy()]
        image = utils.draw_bbox(frame, pred_bbox)
        fps = 1.0 / (time.time() - start_time)
        print("FPS: %.2f" % fps)
        result = np.asarray(image)
        cv2.namedWindow("result", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        result = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        
        if not FLAGS.dont_show:
            cv2.imshow("result", result)
        
        if FLAGS.output:
            out.write(result)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any suggestions for how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the dimensions of frame? You can check it using `frame.shape`

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest using named constants in your calls to `vid.set`, instead of numbers without obvious meaning. you use these named constants in your calls to `vid.get` already.

Answer (score 1):

You created the VideoWriter and set its width and height to 1280 by 720. Later you told it to save 720 by 720 crops. That is the problem. `frame = frame[0:720, 280:1000]` is a 720 by 720 array.

Decide what dimensions your video should have, and use them consistently. A video stream can't change resolution.

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps I'm still missing something. The reason I'm cropping after opening the stream, is that it wasn't possible to set the VideoWriter to 720 x 720. Specifying 720 x 720 gave a corrupted image. I believe this is because (or at least I read somehwere) OpenCV only allows multiples of 32 as dimensions (unless the dimensions are standards, such as 1080 or 720). If I did set it to a multiple of 32, then I got a rectangular frame, with height equal to that specified, but with a larger width, despite setting the width and height as equal?

Comment: why should 720x720 fail when 1280x720 works? you have a working length in *both* dimensions. if something failed or got corrupted, you need to investigate that, or open another post and have it discussed. don't just speculate and be done with it.
still, you give the videowriter frames of a different size than you created it with. that is an error.